# Converting grayscale image pixels to defined scale

Tags: java, heightmap

I'm looking to use a very crude heightmap I've created in Photoshop to define a tiled isometric grid for me:

Map:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4EFu.png

I'm aiming to loop through every pixel in the image and convert the colour of that pixel to a scale of my choosing, for example 0-100.

At the moment I'm using the following code:

```
    try
    {
        final File file = new File("D:\\clouds.png");
        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) 
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) 
            {
                int clr = image.getRGB(x, y) / 99999;
                if (clr <= 0)
                    clr = -clr;

                System.out.println(clr);        
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
         // Deal with exception
    }
```

This works to an extent; the black pixel at position 0 is 167 and the white pixel at position 999 is 0. However when I insert certain pixels into the image I get slightly odd results, for example a gray pixel that's very close to white returns over 100 when I would expect it to be in single digits.

Is there an alternate solution I could use that would yield more reliable results?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a grayscale map, the RGB parts will all be the same value (with range 0 - 255), so just take one out of the packed integer and find out what percent of 255 it is:

```
int clr = (int) ((image.getRGB(x, y) & 0xFF) / 255.0 * 100);

System.out.println(clr);
```

Answer (score 1):

`getRGB` returns all channels packed into one `int` so you shouldn't do arithmetic with it.  Maybe use the norm of the RGB-vector instead?

```java
for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); ++y) {
        final int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
        final int red   = ((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
        final int green = ((rgb & 0x00FF00) >>  8);
        final int blue  = ((rgb & 0x0000FF) >>  0);
        // Norm of RGB vector mapped to the unit interval.
        final double intensity =
            Math.sqrt(red * red + green * green + blue * blue)
            / Math.sqrt(3 * 255 * 255);
    }
}
```

Note that there is also the [`java.awt.Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) class that can be instantiated with the `int` returned by `getRGB` and provides `getRed`, `getGreen` and `getBlue` methods if you don't want to do the bit manipulations yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain in laymans terms what the above code is doing? (specifically the lines with the bitwise operations) Also your code produces a range from 0.4 to 1, how can I adapt it to change the range? Cheers.

Comment: They extract the red, green and blue parts.  See my update mentioning `java.awt.Color`.  You'll probably feel safer with it.  As pointed out by another answer, if your image is *always* grayscale, the three channels will always be the same so you could chose only one of them.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the explanation. I've accepted the other answer because it's simpler and more understandable for me personally. I don't understand the vector norm part well enough to be comfortable using it.